# What should I use the Id property for

Tags: identity, azure-cosmosdb

Documents in documentdb are required to have a unique id property.

Each document also has a document link. This link seems to fulfill much of the role a primary key fulfills in a a relational database table, specifically referring to a unique document.

What should I be using the Id property for vs the document link? If I want to store a stable identifier to a document, are there reasons to store the ID rather than the document link?

Answer (score 1):

Both `id` (which is settable), and `_rid` (which is generated by DocumentDB) are unique keys for a collection, when combined with the configured partition key value. Most applications just use `id`. The primary advantage of `id` is that it is user generated.

There are some advantages to using `_rid` however:

- It is globally unique, yet not as long as a Guid
- It is hierarchical, so you don't need to track database, collection, and document IDs - just the `_rid`
- It is a monotonically increasing value, which is a useful property for some use cases (note: increasing within a partition key, no guaranteed ordering across partition keys)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either choose to use the link field or store the id field and build a link in code. There is only a minuscule cost in latency for the latter, so it's totally up to you which you store as a foreign key. Note, though it's often less round trips to hand build links from ids in non-foreign key circumstances.

A bit of background... The link fields are a bit of legacy, although still useful and probably never going away. When DocumentDB first came out, you couldn't hand build your own links. They fixed this some time in late 2015 or early 2016, if memory serves. I suspect, if they had to do it all over again, they would have done everything with hand-built links using the id.